# How do I overrideMimeType in OpenaLyers.Request.Get

Tags: openlayers-2, xml

I can't find any info on this. When performing a GET request with the following format, I can't figure out how to add the request for "overrideMimeType("application/xml")":

```
request = OpenLayers.Request.GET({
url: "http://aaaaaaaa.com",
async: true,
callback: request_handler,
});
```

An OpenLayers request like this creates the request object and sends it all in this single code. I know if I weren't using the OpenLayers API, I would do something like:

```
request.overrideMimeType("application/xml");
```

But I can't get this to work using using my format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yoy should use `headers` property of `OpenLayers.Request` object:

```js
request = OpenLayers.Request.GET({
    url: "http://aaaaaaaa.com",
    callback: request_handler,
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/xml"
    }
});
```